# Vue: get translations from API

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n, language-translation

I use vue and I18n for translations. In hardcoded translations all works fine:

```
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
const { locale, t } = useI18n({ useScope: 'global' })
```

and from json file get value in template:

```
 <div >{{ t('headers.settings') }}</div>
```

const locale is equal to the lang user choose: 'en', 'fr' etc

For dynamic data I get an API endpoint. The structure looks like this:

```
 data: {
  "key": "Configuration",
  "name": {
   "en": "configuration",
   "nl": "configuratie",
   "fr": "configuration"
 },
  "description": {
   "en": "this is the configuration",
   "nl": "dit is de configuratie",
   "fr": "c'est la configuration"
 },
```

}

so to get name in english it's :

```
<div> {{ data.name.en }} </div>
```

Question: I don't quite understand how to foreach name.en, name.fr, name.nl and display the name.fr if my locale == 'fr' and so on. All idea I have it's:

```
    <div v-if="locale == 'fr' "> {{ data.name.fr }} </div>
    <div v-if="locale == 'en' "> {{ data.name.en }} </div>
```

and so on. May be there is some more effective way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember what you type in there is simply js. you could put the language on a variable on your data object and then use:

```
data: {
  "lang": "en"
}
```

```
<div> {{ data.name[lang] }} </div>
```

you could also re-structure your JSON response to look like this:

```
 data: {
  "lang": "en",
  "translations": {
    "en": {
      "configuration": "configuration",
      "description": "this is the configuration"
    },
    "fr": {
      "configuration": "configuration",
      "description": "c'est la configuration"
    },
    "nl": {
      "configuration": "configuratie",
      "description": "dit is de configuratie"
    }
  }
}
```

then you use in you template:

```
<div> {{ translations[lang].configuration }}</div>
```

this way the variable name in the template becomes more descriptive. you could also on change of language, take the whole object for a language and put it on data directly, so you do not have to refer to it via `translations[lang]` anymore.

Comment: <div> {{ data.name[locale] }} </div>  'locale' in square brackets does its work. Thank you